# Prove that $f(x)$ has either a biggest or lowest value.

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -\infty}{f(x)}=L$. Prove that $f(x)$ has either a biggest or a lowest value in $\mathbb{R}$.

From the task, we can get:

- $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists a>0, \forall x>a: |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$
- $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists b>0, \forall x<-b: |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

But then, what's the next step? The problem reminds me of Weierstrass' theorem:

> If $f(x):[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continous function, then it
> is limited and reaches its biggest and lowest values.

However, I don't think that interpreting $\mathbb{R}$ as a collection of infinitely numerous intervals will make this theorem usable.
Could someone tell me the method of solving this problem, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is constant, we're done. Otherwise and without loss of generality (even if it means changing $f$ into $-f$ and $L$ into $-L$), we can suppose that it exists $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ with $f(x_0) \gt L$.

By definition of the limits, one can find $M \gt 0$ such that

$$f(x) \le \frac{f(x_0) + L}{2} \lt f(x_0)$$ for $\vert x \vert \ge M$. $f$ attains its maximum on the compact interval $[-M,M]$ (that contains $x_0$), which is also a global maximum due to above inequality.

We're done.

Comment: I my God! So simple! Thank you!

Comment: @mfl Indeed! Thanks for noticing the typo that is now corrected.